# format color error for XML

Tags: bug, status-deferred, markdown, design, xml

The colorization auto-formatting doesn't seem to work too well for XML over at SO.  It seems to work properly over here.  Check out the color of the XML at the bottom of this question:
[In XSLT, can I run a template only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344120)

It looks like it is getting confused by the '/' near the end.  It seems to be coloring everything between two '/'s brown, not detecting that that character is part of a closing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Has to be filed against [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), not us.